# How to change action for using brackets?

Tags: notepad++

I would like to change the default action for pressing <kbd>{</kbd> in Notepad++ into the following one:

[image: Example]

So, what I'd like to do when I press `{`

1. `{` should be entered
2. new line should be inserted
3. `}` should be inserted
4. jump to previous line should be made
5. tabulation should be made

How do I do this?

Comment: I fixed my post.

Answer (score 2):

Create a macro in Notepad++, and save it:

1. Start with empty Notepad++ tab.
2. Macro -> Start Recording.
3. Type out how you want it (i.e.: <kbd>{</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>}</kbd>, <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>).
4. Marco -> Stop Recording.
5. Macro -> Save Current Recorded Macro.
6. Give it a name.
7. Select `SHIFT`.
8. Select `[` for the key.
9. OK.

[image: NP++ Macro]

Note: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> = `{` on a standard (US) English keyboard; you may have to adjust to your keyboard and/or personal preferences.

Comment: Awesome way to do this! I just tried it and for some reason it adds a second tab. Probably because notepad already creates a tab when entering the first {.